# Operador lógico || em C# não funciona

Tags: c#, if, operadores, sintaxe

Estou tentando fazer um exercício onde em um intervalo de 0 a 30 quero saber quais número são divisíveis por 3 ou 4. Trabalhando com um `if` para cada situação funciona. Porém se tento usar o operador lógico `||` não funciona. É parte do código que está comentada.

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int iA;

    for (iA = 0; iA <= 30; iA++)
    {
        //if (iA % 3 == 0 || iA % 4 == 0);
        //{
        //    MessageBox.Show(iA + " é múltiplo de 3 ou de 4");
        //}
        if (iA % 3 == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(iA + " é múltiplo de 3");
        }
        else if (iA % 4 == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(iA + " é múltiplo de 4");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Erroe de digitação não estão no escopo do SE

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 9):

O problema é que você está colocando um `;` no `if` e está encerrando ele. O correto seria:

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        for (var iA = 0; iA <= 30; iA++) if (iA % 3 == 0 || iA % 4 == 0) WriteLine(iA + " é múltiplo de 3 ou de 4");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/M0aMzz). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wELIX4). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Syntax/IfBLock.cs).

Answer (score 3):

Sua instrução `if` está sendo encerrada na primeira linha, já que ela possui um `;` com isso, os dois `MessageBox` são chamados sequencialmente.

---

Uma solução paliativa para este cenário é com o uso do [**Linq**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb397906.aspx):
Obs: *Se a intenção for exibir uma mensagem pro usuário a cada ocorrência, então desconsidere.*

```
var listaNumeros = Enumerable.Range(1, 30).Where(p => p % 3 ==0 || p % 4 == 0).ToList();
```

Com o **Linq** você pode:

- Criar uma lista com a quantidade de números sequenciais que desejar;
- Filtrar diretamente nesta lista, conforme suas condições;

Answer (score 1):

Achei o erro. A estrutura if não termina com ";". Grato

Comment: Marque a resposta como como correta.

Comment: Aceite a resposta que melhor atendeu sua necessidade.